# Bind DropdownList with List?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
        var list1 = dbContext.TruckTypes.Where(s => s.Status == "Active").ToList();
        aTypeDropDownList.DataSource = list1;
        aTypeDropDownList.DataTextField = "Name";
        aTypeDropDownList.DataValueField = "Id";
        aTypeDropDownList.DataBind();
```

Error : Additional information: 'aTypeDropDownList' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.

public partial class TruckType
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public TruckType()
        {
            this.Requests = new HashSet();
            this.Trucks = new HashSet();
        }

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public int MaxCapacity { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public double LPriceKM { get; set; }
    public double MPriceKM { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedOn { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Truck> Trucks { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you show TruckType class and markup of aTypeDropDownList?

Comment: Is there a question? The drop downs selected value is not in the list of items, at least that is what the error says. If this is not clear, then what is the question.

Comment: Show the code for setting the SelectedItem

Comment: Could you call `aTypeDropDownList.Items.Clear();` before `aTypeDropDownList.DataSource = list1;`?

Comment: Still Not Workinhg, After aTypeDropDownList.Items.Clear();

Answer (score 1):

When doing `SelectedValue` on a `DropDownList` with database bound values, make sure the value you are setting is actually in the list.

Example, your list contains:

```
<select>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Then you do `SelectedValue = "8"`, this is causing error because value `8` is not in the list.

I really hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

finally i figure-out the problem.
aTypeDropdownLis.text = string.Empty;

i have putted this line in the code.
after removing it, the program working fine.

Comment: You should edit your original question then add the above code to your original question then delete this answer as it is not an answer.

Comment: Please try to read how to use this site before you ask something